# "Report by" or "report from"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is better?

> A new report **by** (Company name) was released today.
>
> A new report **from** (Company name) was released today.

Comment: Could you supply some wider context to fit the phrases into?

Comment: -1, that is my first negative vote. If the doer of the activity is the Arab Advisors then you should use **by**. Simple as that. We **always** use **by** with the doer of the activity. How to find if Arab Advisors are the doer, just ask a simple question with **Who** and the answer should be Arab Advisors. Like **Who has made the new report ?**. You can find it in every simple grammar reference book. The question is not which is better because the both things have different meanings. The question is what I want to say. Mate I have no idea about that. Your tag should be also meaning in context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both prepositions can be used but the meaning won't be the same. **By** means that the report is both submitted and written by the advisers themselves. **From** means that the advisers sumbit the report, but it isn't clear who writes it. Since the use of **by** leaves no ambiguities, it is probably the best choice.